# Pyraf rspectext RuntimeError: dictionary keys changed during iteration

Tags: python, bash, iraf

I have to convert a classic ascii file with two columns (wavelength and flux) into a fits file and I used rspectext from pyraf (with dtype=interp) in a python script but I get this error message:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
File "<CL script CL1>", line 1, in <module>
File "<CL script onedspec.rspectext>", line 54, in rspectext
    iraf.hedit(Vars.specout, 'title', Vars.title, add=yes, 
    addonly=no,PYdel=no,update=yes,verify=no,show=no)
RuntimeError: dictionary keys changed during iteration
```

I cannot understand what is wrong. I updated everything, followed guides to install both iraf and pyraf and on iraf, rspectext works. In other python scripts I use other commands like continuum, splot etc. and they work.

My script for a test is simply:

```
from pyraf.iraf import onedspec,rspectext
onedspec
rspectext(input='test.dat',output='spectrum',dtype='interp')
```

A very short version of the spectrum with which i am testing is:

```
5530.01708984375 0.9749500155448914
5530.0498046875 0.9674800038337708
5530.0830078125 0.9679499864578247
5530.1162109375 0.968280017375946
5530.1474609375 0.9703999757766724
5530.18115234375 0.9549300074577332
5530.21435546875 0.9670699834823608
5530.2470703125 0.9639800190925598
5530.2802734375 0.953029990196228
5530.31298828125 0.9535700082778931
5530.34619140625 0.9583899974822998
5530.37890625 0.9467300176620483
5530.412109375 0.9565500020980835
```

python version 3.10.6
pyraf version 2.2.0
iraf 2.17
OS Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 64bit

It is ok also if you have suggestions for alternative ways to normalise a spectrum using python.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: _dictionary keys changed during iteration_ means that in `rspectext`,  you are iterating over a dictionary, and while doing this, you are modifying this dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is actually a bug in PyRAF 2.2.0, which is fixed in 2.2.1. See [iraf-community/pyraf#146](https://github.com/iraf-community/pyraf/issues/146) for details. So the way to fix this is to upgrade to 2.2.1.